# Isotope Dropdown select filtering with hash history integration

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, hash, jquery-isotope

Can anyone tell me how to integrate an isotope dropdown with hash history?

Thanks!

I found a solution! Here is the code for anybody it needs!

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav id="filterGroup" class="clearfix">

   <select id="projects" class="filter option-set clearfix" data-filter-group="proyectos" onchange="selectProject()">
          <option data-filter-value="*" selected="selected">todos</option>  
          <option data-filter-value=".laywers">laywers</option>  
          <option data-filter-value=".computers">computers</option>  
          <option data-filter-value=".construction">construction</option>  
          <option data-filter-value=".consultants">consultants</option>                                      
    </select>

</nav> <!-- nav -->
```

Isotope dropdown code:

```
$(function() {
    var $container = $('#container'),
        $select = $('nav#filterGroup select');
    filters = {};

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.element'
    });
        $select.change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        var $optionSet = $this;
        var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
    filters[group] = $this.find('option:selected').attr('data-filter-value');

        var isoFilters = [];
        for (var prop in filters) {
            isoFilters.push(filters[prop])
        }
        var selector = isoFilters.join('');

        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Then finally add the code to change value names:

```
    function selectProject(){
    var projects = document.getElementById('projects');
    var selectedProject = projects.options[projects.selectedIndex];
    if (selectedProject.value != "*"){
            window.location.hash = selectedProject.value;
    }
}
```

Checj it out! It works!

Comment: I found a solution! Here is the code for anyone needed!

Isotope dropdpwn code: